# Storing json object in Padrino CouchDB model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, couchdb, padrino

I’m currently working on [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/) application with [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) backend. I need to have a model to store json besides some general strings. The model looks like (in pseudocode):

```
name: 'UniqueName',
properties: { prop1: val1, prop2: val2 }
```

I can’t predict how many values of which types are to be stored in `properties`. Currently I use the generic model:

```
padrino g model MyModel name:string, properties:string
```

Before storing properties, I stringify json; on loading I create json from string. I feel that I’m doing wrong. Since CouchDB is ready to store json objects as is, I wonder if there is a way to tell Padrino’s model that the latter field is json for it to be stored natively? Like:

```
name: 'UniqueName',
properies:
  - prop1: val1, 
  - prop2: val2
```

I see that I could create a separate collection and refer it by `_id` from `MyModel`, but at the moment I want to store it alongside it’s `name`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to stringify json, just parse it and store as an array using the JSON standard lib.

```
original JSON data example:
json_data = [{ prop1: val1, prop2: val2, prop3: val3 }] #store the JSON data from wherever it came
parsed = JSON.parse(json_data.to_json) #store the parsed JSON data into an Array

foo = MyModel.find(1) #find whatever collection you wanna update
foo.properties = parsed
# => [{ prop1: val1, prop2: val2, prop3: val3 }]
foo.save
```

Your MyModel should then look like the following:

```
{
  "_id" : "your_generated_id",
  "_rev" : "your_generated_rev",
  "name" : "UniqueName",
  "properties" : [
         { 
           prop1: val1, 
           prop2: val2, 
           prop3: val3 
         }
  ]
}
```

Remember CouchDB is "schemaless". More details [here](https://cloudant.com/blog/schemas-in-couchdb/#.VF7hlfTF_B0).

Comment: I see CouchDB is schemaless. The only question remains: how did I describe migration, e.g. padrino/rails model? Migration is likely to be ORM-independent and I want to keep it so.

Comment: Padrino uses the [CouchRest ORM](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest) to talk to CouchDB. What you're trying to do is what's called Casting. See the section [CouchRest - Property Arrays](http://www.couchrest.info/model/properties.html) in Model Properties. Also see [CouchRest_ExtendDocument](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_extended_document#general) documentation. So to answer your question, the model/migration would be `property :properties, [String]`